# Resources for UI Architectural Concepts

Tags: users

I started getting my hands around some of the following UI related concepts but I thought it would be wise to request the experts I am aware of along these lines…

• UI Design Concepts (Principles around Wireframes, Usability concepts, common pitfalls and how to avoid them and so on…)

• UI Methodologies (What are various available methodologies (Applets, Standard web apps, portal based, mash up based) for UIs, and which methodology applies for which scenario).

• UI Technologies / Frameworks (there are various technologies (like Struts, Spring, JSF [myfaces, ice faces], dojo, JQuery) and various frameworks within a technology, how to choose what is best for the usecase in hand?) may be not to learn detailed of all of them but to be able to classify these and be able to identify which technology might fit for the situation.

And anything else I am missing from a UI Architure perspective …

Please suggest me to some good websites I should be following or experts I should be in touch with or free training on these concepts that you are aware of …

I highly appreciate if you can point me to any webcasts or open source groups that are working on UI Architectural areas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote an article titled "[24 inspirational blogs, books and articles on user interface patterns](http://www.paulolyslager.com/inspirational-blogs-books-articles-user-interface-patterns)". It's a list of resources that I keep close whenever I start a new project. I hope you'll find what you need.

Comment: Good list of items. It'd be great if you could put some of them directly in the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The topics you mention are very broad. I found a [selection of videos](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/05/25-user-experience-videos-that-are-worth-your-time/) that cover some of these topics.

This can be the starting point. Then if you start to follow the contributors of the videos (e.g., using twitter) you will have access to relevant information on these topics.

Answer (score 0):

As asked for, a small section of of my collection of blogs, books and articles on User Interface.

**Blogs**

[Ui Patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/)

[Pattern Tab](http://patterntap.com/)

[Patternry](http://www.patternry.com/)

[Yahoo! Design Pattern Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/)

[Boxes and arrows](http://www.boxesandarrows.com/)

**Articles**

[Interface 101 by Fuel Your Interface](http://www.fuelyourinterface.com/interface-101-part-one-basic-interfaces/)

[Design Patterns by LukeW](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?347)

[Human Interface Design Principles by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGHIDesign/XHIGHIDesign.html)

**Books**

[“Designing Web Interfaces: Principles and Patters for Rich Interactions” by Bill Scott and Theresa Neil](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596516258)

[“Designing Interfaces: Patterns for Effective Interaction Design” by Jenifer Tidwell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596008031)